# Cron Failure - Mage_Core_Exception

Tags: event-observer, cron, magento-core, callback

I get this from the error log all the time.

Cron Failure catalog_product alert:

**---EXCEPTION---**

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback: Model
>   for productalert/observer::process does not exist' in Mage.php:598
>
> This is line 598: throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message); and this is
>   the entire section of

```
/**
     * Throw Exception
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @param string $messageStorage
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     */
    public static function throwException($message, $messageStorage = null)
    {
        if ($messageStorage && ($storage = self::getSingleton($messageStorage))) {
            $storage->addError($message);
        }
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

productalert/observer::process no longer exists.

Search codebase for productalert. XML is making magento look for

[Vendor]_[Extension]_Model_Observer

`public function process() {`

productalert will be in XML. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html

There is a refence to this event in XML too under `<events>` node in XML

[Magento 1.9 how to create custom events](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140364/magento-1-9-how-to-create-custom-events)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out Mage_ProductAlert was false in /app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml. Change to true and the error not showing anymore.